# Nginx redirect if not host and if not request uri

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

Can anyone see why the following Nginx if statements doesn't work

```
if ($host != subdomain.mydomain.com) {
    set $test  A;
}

if ($request_uri != /.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*?)) {
  set $test  "${test}B";
}

if ($test = AB) {
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.anotherdomain/$1 permanent;
  break
}
```

In English, if the host is not subdomain.mydomain.com and the request URI is not /.well-known/acme-challenge/* then I want it to redirect to another domain

Answer (score 0):

The following code in the end worked for me

```
if ($host != subdomain.mydomain.com) {
    set $test  A;
}

if ($request_uri !~ /\.well-known) {
      set $test  "${test}B";
}

if ($test = AB) {
  rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.anotherdomain/$1 permanent;
  break
}
```